# Cayley on "trivial transformations"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, math-history, periodic-functions

In his 1854 paper, "Deuxième mémoire sur les fonctions doublement périodiques" ("Second memoir on doubly periodic functions"), Cayley discusses (what we would today describe as) a certain class of transformations 
$\mathbb C^2 \rightarrow \mathbb C^2$
 corresponding to matrices 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & \mu \\
\nu & \rho \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with integer entries. Up to sign, Cayley requires the determinant $\lambda\rho-\mu\nu$
  of such a matrix to be an odd prime number. Moreover, for every pair of complex numbers $\left(\Omega,\Upsilon\right)$, all such transformations are required to satisfy the conditions $$\lambda\Omega+\mu\Upsilon=\left(2k+1\right)\Omega,$$
$$\nu\Omega+\rho\Upsilon=\left(2k+1\right)\Upsilon,$$
 where $2k+1=\left|\lambda\rho-\mu\nu\right|$
  is a positive odd prime, equal up to sign to the matrix determinant.

Cayley calls such a transformation ‘proper’ (*propre*) if $2k+1=\lambda\rho-\mu\nu$
  (i.e., if the determinant is itself positive), and ‘regular’ (*régulière*) if both $\lambda$
  and $\rho$
  are odd and both $\mu$
  and $\nu$
  are even. He says that all transformations mentioned in the "Deuxième Mémoire" will be assumed proper and regular. After introducing these conditions and making some basic observations, Cayley says, “Je suppose d'abord que $2k+1$
  soit égal à l'unité, transformation que l’on peut nommer *triviale*.” (“I suppose first that $2k+1$
  may be equal to unity, a transformation that one could call *trivial*.”)

In other words, a trivial transformation in Cayley's sense is a proper and regular map $\mathbb{C}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{2}$
  corresponding to an integer matrix with determinant $1$, and such that the matrix entries satisfy the two equations mentioned above.

My question (finally) is this: Besides the transformation corresponding to the identity matrix $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right],$$ what are some examples of trivial transformations in Cayley's sense? What do such transformations look like in general?

Comment: Are you sure it's for "every pair of complex numbers $\left(\Omega,\Upsilon\right)$"? Setting $\Omega=0$ we get $\mu=0$, and so forth. In fact, we have $\mu=\nu=0$, $\lambda\rho$ is prime, so one of them is $1$ and the other is prime. But they both must satisfy the two equations (which I started with), so they both must be equal and hence $1$. Therefore the identity matrix is the only matrix satisfying the conditions... I must be misunderstanding something you wrote; could you please clarify?

Comment: @NotNotLogical: That certainly seems right. Hence my puzzlement, since Cayley later speaks of _a_ trivial transformation, implying that many such transformations exist. Let me quote the beginning of the paper, when Cayley first introduces Ω and Υ.

Comment: @NotNotLogical: First the French: "Avant d'entrer en matiere, je remarque que partant des expressions $\Omega = \omega + \omega' i$, $\Nu = \nu + \nu' i$, des deux periodes, ou $i = \sqrt{-1}$," etc. (He then goes on to note some facts that I don't think are relevant to the issue at hand.) This seems to say: "Before entering in to the matter, I note that starting with the expressions $\Omega = \omega + \omega' i, \Nu = \nu + \nu' i$, of two periods, where $i = \sqrt{-1}$", etc.

Comment: Oops, that should be $\Upsilon$, not $\Nu$.

Comment: @NotNotLogical: The weird thing to me is the expression "of two periods". It sounds like he's saying that $\Omega$ and $\Upsilon$ are complex numbers with two periods, which is nonsensical. But I don't know how else to interpret him.

Comment: Perhaps it is "of the two periods", and he has already specified what those periods are? Could you perhaps provide a link to what you are reading (optimally English translation, but I know some French so that's fine - it looks like you found the original article)? I think that would help to give more context. Cheers!

Comment: Nevermind, I found it online - I'll let you know if I figure anything out.

Comment: I think upon reading the first part of the article, that $\Omega$ and $\Upsilon$ are *fixed*, not varying. So for given $\Omega$ and $\Upsilon$, we must find integers $\lambda, \mu, \nu, \rho$ such that the conditions hold.